# using Gerund for object

Tags: expression, gerund

In English, when we are thankful to God that my mother gave us the money, we say
`We thanked God for her giving us the money`, using gerund and the possesive pronoun for the semantic subject of the gerund.
Can we do this in German like this (changing the verb to noun):

> Wir dankten Gott für ihr uns das Geld Geben.

(I know usually you'd say `Wir dankten Gott, dass sie uns das Geld gab.`)

Comment: The closest appropriation was "Wir dankten Gott ihrer dafür, sie, uns das Geld gebend" LOL. But this sounds as if a timetraveler from the medieval is speaking to you. Today it is simply wrong. But it lets us adumbrate how both languages were similar ages ago. Sometimes Gerund seems to work like Partizip 1 but actually it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no direct way of doing that. To make a verb into a noun, you'd usually go, e.g. "geben" -> "(es ... ), dass ... gibt" E.g.:

> Es stört mich, dass sie mir kein Geld gibt. ("Her not giving money to me annoys me")

In your sentence, you'd have something like "Wir dankten Gott für es, dass sie<sup>1</sup> uns das Geld gibt", where "für es" becomes "dafür", resulting in:

> Wir dankten Gott dafür, dass sie uns das Geld gibt.

There are some cases where you'd nominalise more complicated phrases, especially when you talk rather than write:

> Sein ständiges Über-seinen-Hund-Schimpfen geht mir auf die Nerven.

This is rare (and frowned upon) in written texts though, although there might be some philosophical texts around where they couldn't get around it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! (But I meant we thanked God that my mother gave us the money).